# Regex to capture some ID from URL if that URL does not contain banned text

Tags: regex, url

I have the following regex that I created to locate a 10 digit id (ideally it would not consider set of digits that more than 10 e.g. id=12345678901). After it finds the last set of 10 digits, it would trash everything that comes after it EXcept when it hits brackets or quotes. In that case it would just stop.

```
 www.site1\.com\/((?!someid\=12345name).)*([0-9]{10})[^\"\'\[\]\n\s]*
```

However, in examples like below, it does not stop at a bracker or quiotation after the 10 digit number and keeps going untill it find another one:

[URL='http://www.site1.com/path/445-453/L?test=3456&test2=333629710&item=1058371930']Some Title of    This URL[/URL]or [URL='http://www.site1.com/path/445-453/L?test=3456&test2=333629710&item=2932475321']Some url title 2[/URL]

See live url for more examples: http://regex101.com/r/pG5fA4/2

FYI - notice some links have the same parameters with 10 digit ids in it. As it is now, I would like it to select only the last set of 10 digits as long as it does not go over looking after brackets or quotations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a **greedy** operator. Because of the greedy operator, `.*` will match all characters (except newline) until it reaches the last set of digits at the very end of the string. Use `*?` for a non-greedy match. This guarantees that the quantified dot will only match as many characters as needed for the pattern to succeed.

```
((?!someid\=12345name).)*?([0-9]{10})
                         ^
```

If you want the set of digits before the last `&`, `'` `[` or `]` you can use a lookahead.

```
www\.site1\.com/((?!someid=12345name).)*?([0-9]{10})(?=[\[\]'\s]|&[^&]*\n)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely something helpful. The only thing from perfect is that I now noticed the new regex is pulling the first set of 10 digits it finds, not the last. Is there anyway to allow it to select the last set of digits before a bracket or quote?

Comment: -- I cant remove the charclass at the end because I want to remove all the trash after the 10 digit id and before a bracket or quote after I rewrite the url.
-- Actually, I don't think I will ever have two sets of 10 character digits so not sure why I worried about that and your regex shoudl work too.
-- Anyway, I also tried the following and it gave good results: www.site1\.com\/((?!someid\=12345name)[^\"\'\[\]\n\s])*([0-9]{10})[^\"\'\[\]\n\s]* --  http://regex101.com/r/pG5fA4/4